# Running a shell script in CloudFormation cfn-init

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to run a script in the cfn-init command but it keeps timing out.
What am I doing wrong when running the startup-script.sh?

```
"WebServerInstance" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "DependsOn" : "AttachGateway",
      "Metadata" : {
        "Comment" : "Install a simple application",
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
          "config" : {
            "files": {
              "/home/ec2-user/startup_script.sh": {
                "content": {
                  "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                      "#!/bin/bash\n",
                      "aws s3 cp s3://server-assets/startserver.jar . --region=ap-northeast-1\n",
                      "aws s3 cp s3://server-assets/site-home-sprint2.jar . --region=ap-northeast-1\n",
                      "java -jar startserver.jar\n",
                      "java -jar site-home-sprint2.jar --spring.datasource.password=`< password.txt` --spring.datasource.username=`< username.txt` --spring.datasource.url=`<db_url.txt`\n"
                    ]
                  ]
                },
                "mode": "000755"
              }
            },
            "commands": {
              "start_server": {
                "command": "./startup_script.sh",
                "cwd": "~",
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

The file part works fine and it creates the file but it times out at running the command. 
What is the correct way of executing a shell script?

Comment: You say "it's timing out": is it because the script hangs or does it run so long that you exceed the default time-out?

Answer (score 1):

You can tail the logs in `/var/log/cfn-init.log` and detect the issues while running the script.

The commands in Cloudformation Init are ran as `sudo user` by default. Maybe there can be an issue were your script is residing in `/home/ec2-user/` and you are trying to run the script from `'~' (i.e. /root)`.

Please give the absolute path `(/home/ec2-user)` in `cwd`. It will solve your concern.

However, the exact issue can be fetched from the logs only.

Answer (score -1):

Usually the init scripts are executed by root unless specified otherwise. Can you try giving the full path while running your startup script. You can give [cloudkast](https://krunal4amity.github.io) a try. It is an online cloudformation template generator. Makes easier creating objects such as aws::cloudformation::init.